jinja2 and flask issue
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block head %}
<title>Task Master</title>
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<div class="content">
    <h1>Task Master</h1>
    {% if tasks|length < 1 %}
    <h4 style="text-align: center">There are no tasks. Create one below!</h4>
    {% else %}
    <table class="center">
        <tr>
            <th>Task</th>
            <th>Added</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        {% for task in tasks %}
            <tr>
            <td> {{ task.content }}</td>
            <td> {{ task.date_created.date()}}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="/delete/{{task.id}}">Delete</a>
                <br>
                <a href="/update/{{task.id}}">Update</a>
            </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    {% endif %}
    <hr width="100%">
    <form action="/" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="content" id="content"></input>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Task"></input>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}

Hello guys i have a problem in my code that if the use doesn't write any task it can be stored as a task even when i am doing an if else statement i don't know if there is any solution

The description of your problem is very difficult for me to understand. Please describe what you expect, for which purpose and what happens instead.

@Detlef okay , i was following a tuto about flask the goal is to create a to do task using it . i didnt follow each step exactly so now i want when a user don't type anything and press add task i want the code to show them this message There are no tasks. Create one below! if it writes one caracter it works normally

If I understand you correctly, you want to prevent the user from creating a task that has no content.
To achieve this, it is possible to add a required attribute to the input field for the content. This way, the form will not be sent until the user has made an entry.
In addition, however, it is also necessary to validate the entries on the server.
You could output the message using the flash(...) command in Flask.
Below is an example application in which the user receives a message if they have made an incorrect entry.
from datetime import datetime
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    flash, 
    redirect, 
    render_template, 
    request, 
    url_for
)
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.sql import func 
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase 

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_mapping(
    SECRET_KEY='your secret here',
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='sqlite:///example.db'
)
db = SQLAlchemy(app, model_class=Base)

class Task(db.Model):
    id: db.Mapped[int] = db.mapped_column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content: db.Mapped[str] = db.mapped_column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    date_created: db.Mapped[datetime] = db.mapped_column(
        db.DateTime(timezone=True), 
        nullable=False, 
        server_default=func.now()
    )

with app.app_context():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        content = request.form.get('content', '').strip()
        if content: 
            task = Task(content=content)
            db.session.add(task)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('.index'))
        
        flash('Please provide content when creating a task.')

    stmt = db.select(Task)
    tasks = db.session.execute(stmt).scalars().all()

    return render_template('index.html', **locals())

# ...

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Task Master</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Task Master</h1>

        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
            {% if messages %}
            <ul>
                {% for category, message in messages %}
                <li>{{ message }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}

        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" name="content" id="content" required />
            <input type="submit" value="Add Task" />
        </form>
        <hr/>
        {% if tasks  %}
        <table class="center">
            <tr>
                <th>Task</th>
                <th>Added</th>
                <!-- ... -->
            </tr>
            {% for task in tasks %}
            <tr>
                <td> {{ task.content }}</td>
                <td> {{ task.date_created.date()}}</td>
                <!-- ... -->
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
        {% else %}
        <h4 style="text-align: center">There are currently no tasks.</h4>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>

